# How to read a file from internal storage?

Tags: java, android

I've just created a file in MainActivity using the code:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.close();
```

Now what to use if I want to read the file (noting that the file will be obviously created in the internal storage)?

And is there a way that makes the file reading works as the *Scanner* function in Java (where the string is being read word by word and line by line)?

Answer (score 1):

Use openFileInput() with the same parameters as openFileOutput().

Comment: Thanks! So how exactly do I read the file? What should I write further?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more and write it in code format and give an example (Sorry if this makes me seem like an idiot), also not to mention I am a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution what I understood from your question,

```
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(new File("FILE_PATH"));

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(fIn));

String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
```